# LaTeX Presentation Cubic transition effect

Tags: beamer

I have seen some presentations that use a kind of cubic effect when moving between pages. For instance, suppose you have a cube and every page is a side of the cube, then when moving from page one to page two, the page is changed with 3d effect of turning the cube from edge to edge. I know the presentation is typeset in LaTeX but I don't know this feature is LaTeX relevant or not.
How can I have that 3d effect in LaTeX presentation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you need a special presentation software, such as [impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) or [pdfcube](http://code.100allora.it/pdfcube).  You create a pdf presentation using one of the LaTeX packages or classes designed for that purpose (such as beamer, prosper, powerdot, ppower4), and present it using a special software.

Note that number of people find fancy page transitions like that highly distracting, so it may not be always the best idea.

Comment: Yup, they’re horrible. The effect is a complete logical disconnect with the content of the presentation – unless you’re currently talking about rotating cubes – which means that it’s a distraction and doesn’t belong.

Comment: Fancy transitions have a place in presentations which are not meant to be narrated.  Like things that are running on a screen in a kiosk.  For talks, however, I try to make sure the presentation is not more interesting than me.

Comment: +1 for the tone of the answer: pointing out why this is often a bad idea, but first of all, respecting the author’s judgement and giving a good answer to the original question.